# Individually accessing each element inside a div with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site where all my info is inside a div. Most of the elemenst inside do not have a unique identifier which has me stumped on how to pull all the info out individually. Here is the code I am trying to pull from.

```
<div class="message-userExtras">
            
    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Joined</dt>
    <dd>Feb 23, 2023</dd>
    </dl>


    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Messages</dt>
    <dd>22</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Reaction score</dt>
    <dd>
    <a href="/members/297754/reactions-info" class="link">18</a>
    </dd>
    </dl>
                    
                                        
    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Escrow deals</dt>
    <dd>3</dd>
    </dl>
                    

    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Deposit</dt>
    <dd><a class="deposit-button" href="/members/297754/deposit" data-xf-click="overlay">0.1 <i class="fa--xf fab fa-btc deposit-fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

An example of the formatted info would be:

> 'joined': ['Feb 23, 2023'], 'messages': ['22'], 'reaction score': ['18'], 'escrow deals': ['3'], 'deposit': ['0.1']}

Any help on how to access these elements individually would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS Selector to get the list of all similar web elements. And then filter through them. You can try something like:

```py
dl_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.message-userExtras dl')
output = {}
for element in dl_list:
   dt_value = element.find_element_by_tag_name('dt').text
   dd_ = element.find_element_by_tag_name('dd')
   if 'href' in dd_.get_attribute('innerHTML'):
       dd_value = dd_.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
   else:
       dd_value = dd_.text
   output[dt_value] = dd_value

print(output)
```